# Problem with flutter fresh install, not working, on Windows 10

Tags: windows, flutter, dart

I just installed Flutter following the instructions from https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows, but when I run flutter doctor it does nothing after checking the flutter version, it gets stuck and doesn't check for Android toolchain or anything else.

```
C:\Users\JUAN>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.885], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.7.8+hotfix.3 at C:\Users\JUAN\Documents\flutter
    • Framework revision b712a172f9 (4 weeks ago), 2019-07-09 13:14:38 -0700
    • Engine revision 54ad777fd2
    • Dart version 2.4.0

\
```

It gets stuck after that.
Does someone has any insight about what the problem might be?
I've already tried reinstalling flutter, android studio, setting the PATH environment variables, I don't know what's wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the exact output of 'flutter doctor' for effective help.

Comment: That's the exact output, it stops there, at the "\". That's where it gets stuck.

Comment: Do you install android studio and android sdk?

Comment: Yes, I installed Android studio and android sdk

Answer (score -1):

That happened to me once on a company computer that for some reason didn't have a proper Java installation. Fixing Java fixed flutter and it was able to run without a problem.